# VMWare converter: Can it do static conversion from Hyper-V or does it require connection to ESX?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, ovf

We have a Hyper-V host and are moving the VMs to VMWare ESX.

[VMWare Converter](https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html) seems to be the only tool available. (I thought Hyper-V could save/export to OVF, but I seem to be mistaken.)

The question is: Can VMWare Converter do a static conversion on disk, from Hyper-V to OVF or ESX formats, without a connection to ESX, or does it require a login to ESX to do the conversion?

(We need to break the process up, because access to ESX/VCenter/VSphere is highly restricted in our environment.)

Comment: There are bunch of other tools available actually. http://www.vmwareblog.org/v2v-converters-overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only supports a certain subset of targets (https://www.vmware.com/pdf/convsa_55_guide.pdf , page 20).  I recommend downloading VMWare Workstation and converting with that as your target.  You can test the resulting VM in Workstation, and then migrate it from Workstation to ESXi / vCenter when your security folks give you access.  https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005129

Supported Converter destination types:

> VMware vCenter virtual machines Managed destinations
>
> - ESX
> - ESXi
> - vCenter Server
>
> VMware hosted virtual machines Hosted destinations
>
> - VMWare Workstation
> - VMWare Fusion
> - VMWare Player

Comment: Rob, that is a good set of suggestions. We don't have VMWare Workstation avail in the DC, but we don't really need to test. We just need to convert (the conversion will either fly or fail, we can discover that on esx just as easily). We will convert to VMWare Workstation, pull into ESX, and see how things look!

Comment: Glad to be of help!